# How to exclude 404 error messages from logging to email?

Tags: django

Good afternoon. I have this type of logs in the settings:

```python
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },

    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '{levelname} {asctime} {module} {process:d} {thread:d} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '{levelname} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
    },

    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },

        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'include_html': True,
        },
    },

    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'mail_admins'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    }
}
```

I receive all messages of the level of warning and above in the email.
Due to various robots, spammers or other users looking for hidden files and folders, I get a lot of 404 (page not found) error messages.

How can I stop receiving information about 404 errors?

Answer (score 0):

This is thanks to the mail_admins handler, that sends you any WARNING level and above error by email, [see doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/logging/#django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler)

As suggested in docs, you can subclass this handler and use your new custom handler instead.

```py
class MyCustomHandler(AdminEmailHandler):
    """Custom Handler that ignores 404 errors instead of sending them by email"""
    def handle(self, record):
        if record.exc_info:
            exc_type, exc_value, tb = record.exc_info
            if isinstance(exc_value, Http404):
                return
        super().handle(record)
```

Comment: Yes, I tried to figure out the class, but I just can’t figure out how to get the response code in the emit method in order to exclude only 404 pages

Comment: I edited the comment with an example, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: For some reason, in this case, record.exc_info = None

Comment: Hmm it's possible that this example is incomplete or wrong, I didn't try it myself to be honest. However the final code should look for the exception's class to filter, I didn't look in details to see where you could get that, maybe pdb and inspect will help you with that.